# Mocking an object retaining its functionality in Python

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I'm testing the behavior of an object. In the sample code below, I check if the method `bar2` is called.

The debug print shows that yes, `bar2` is called. Unfortunately, the `mock`-library doesn't track this call.

What should I do to make `mock` to notice such "internal" calls?

```
import mock

class Foo:
  def bar1(self):
    print "in bar1"
    self.bar2()
  def bar2(self):
    print "in bar2"

m = mock.Mock(wraps = Foo())
m.bar1()
print "Method calls:", m.method_calls
m.bar2.assert_called_with()
```

Output:

```
in bar1
in bar2
Method calls: [call.bar1()]
...
AssertionError: Expected call: bar2()
Not called
```

**Update**

I've accepted the answer with patching as the methodically correct, but would like also to show my direct approach:

```
obj = Foo()
m = mock.Mock(wraps = obj)
obj.bar2 = m.bar2 # Patch the object manually

m.bar1()

m.bar2.assert_called_with()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't. You mocked out `Foo()`, so the implementation is gone; the whole point of mocking is to replace the class.

If you are testing `Foo` itself, don't mock the class. You can mock individual methods instead:

```
with mock.patch('__main__.Foo.bar2') as bar2_mock:
    f = Foo()
    f.bar1()
    print "Method calls:", bar2_mock.method_calls
    bar2_mock.assert_called_with()
```

This outputs:

```
in bar1
Method calls: []
```

as now only `bar2` has been mocked.